# Factoring a logical expression containing bitwise operators AND and SHIFT

Tags: refactoring, operators, logic, bitwise-operators

I have a logical expression like this: (A << k) & (A << l) where A is a variable and k, l are integers. I want to factorize this expression so that one part contains only A and the other part is anything without A. In other words:

(A << k) & (A << l) = A op1 (anything not containing A)

Can anyone tell what is the operator op1 and the "(anything not containing A)"? Or whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, the best I can do is to move one of the shifts

```
assuming k > l (otherwise switch them)

A & ( A << (k-l) ) << l
```

but that's obviously not what you're after